# Is there a way to add a wrapper div around a silverstripe form field

Tags: php, html, forms, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

Is there a way to add a wrapper around a labelfield or any other kind of form field in silverstripe forms? 
It would be easier to style forms this way.

```
FieldList::create(
    LabelField::create('label','Label'),
    EmailField::create('Email',''),
    TextareaField::create('Comment','')
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to the docs you can set a template either per form or per field, [see docs.](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/forms/form_templates/)

```
$field = TextField::create(..);
$field->setTemplate('MyCustomTextField');
```

You need to set the whole path to your template if it's located in a subfolder of your themes `/templates/` directory.

If you need to change the templates globally you can overwrite them in your theme. LabelField's template is located in [`templates/SilverStripe/Forms/LabelField.ss`](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/4/templates/SilverStripe/Forms/LabelField.ss).

1. Put a file with the same path in your theme (e.g.
   `themes/mytheme/templates/SilverStripe/Forms/LabelField.ss`),
2. flush your Silverstripe cache (e.g. by running flush by adding `?flush` to the URL) so Silverstripe can find the new
   template file,
3. and start experimenting with your custom markup.

A flush is only needed when you add a new template file, updates of your existing files will be detected automatically.